# Vertical alignment of nested aligns

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment, align

I would like to align a rather complicated formula, consisting of
an (outer) optimization problem with several (inner) constraint blocks, which
should be aligned around equal signs. I have opted to use nested `align`s and got around to this:

```
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    \min_{\vec{y}, \vec{v}}\ & f(\vec{y}) + g(\vec{v})  \\
    \textrm{s.t. } &
    \begin{aligned}
      \dot{\vec{y}} & = f(\vec{y}, \vec{v}) \\
      \vec{y}(0) & = \vec{y}_0 \\
    \end{aligned}
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

which yields the following result:

[image: rendered code]

Unfortunately, the `s.t.` is centered with respect to the constraint block, whereas I need both blocks to be aligned at their respective tops, so I need the `s.t.` to come up.

How can I adjust the code to achieve this effect?

Comment: Use the `[t]` option with `aligned`. However, note there exists a dedicated package, `optidef`, which works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    \min_{\vec{y}, \vec{v}}\ & f(\vec{y}) + g(\vec{v})  \\
    \textrm{s.t. } &
    \begin{aligned}[t]
      \dot{\vec{y}} & = f(\vec{y}, \vec{v}) \\
      \vec{y}(0) & = \vec{y}_0 \\
    \end{aligned}
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is a dedicated package, `optidef` which simplifies the typing and has many options. Here is a demo of three possibilities, the last two using  vector arrows from the `esvect` package, which look nicer than the default `\vec` (8 different arrow tips). Also, I prefer not to align the constraints on the = sign:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[short]{optidef}
\usepackage[f]{esvect}

\begin{document}

\begin{mini}{\vec{y}, \vec{v}}{ f(\vec{y}) + g(\vec{v})}{\label{eq: example}}{}
  \addConstraint{\dot{\vec{y}}}{ = f(\vec{y}, \vec{v})}
  \addConstraint{\vec{y}(0)}{ = \vec{y}_0}
\end{mini}


\begin{mini!}{\vv{y}, \vv{v}}{ f(\vv{y}) + g(\vv{v})}{\label{eq: example}}{}
  \addConstraint{\vrule}{\dot{\vv{y}} = f(\vv{y}, \vv{v})}
  \addConstraint{\vrule}{\vv{y}(0) = \vv*{y}{0}\notag}
\end{mini!}

\begin{mini!}{\vv{y}, \vv{v}}{ f(\vv{y}) + g(\vv{v})}{\label{eq: example}}{}
  \addConstraint{\begin{array}[t]{|@{\,}l}\dot{\vv{y}} = f(\vv{y}, \vv{v})\\
  \vv{y}(0) = \vv*{y}{0}\end{array}}{}
\end{mini!}

\end{document}
```

[image]